# I can not install the Solana CLI on WSL: Ubuntu

Tags: solana-program

I just recently started learning Solana and I'm configuring a local environment for my computer. Following the instructions at https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local, I ran sh -c "$(curl - sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)", but the terminal displays curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading. I googled this problem but couldn't find a solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all of your packages and check if that will resolve your issue:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: After I run this. It still shows curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading.

Comment: try to upgrade curl: 'apt-get upgrade curl', what is the output?

Comment: It still shows curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading.